# Skype for Business - recording manager - recording not finished

Tags: skype-for-business

I used Skype for Business during a training session to record audio and screen sharing to document a process on Friday afternoon, for about a 3 hour session that originally thought would be an hour long.  After the training was over and stopped recording, I did not bother to check the Skype for Business recording manager to ensure the recording was finished processing, and shut down my computer.

To my horror, this morning when I opened the recording manager, I saw this:

[image: recording manager listing]

My recording from Friday had a size of 0 MB.  I looked at the directory location listed, and there was no file by that name.  I checked the following locations also, with no luck:

- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
- C:\temp
- C:\WINDOWS\temp

Is there any way to recover the recording?

Version information:

- Windows version: Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1
- Skype for Business Recording Manager version 15.0.4849.1000

Comment: Sorry, edited and added the implied question: "can I recover the recording?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was able to restore the recording. Steps:

1. Start a new Skype for Business meeting, share the screen and turn on the recording.
2. Pause the recording.
3. Find temp files for the current recording in `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\Recording Manager\Temporary Recording Files\`.
4. Remove all files except `lock.lock` file.
5. Copy temp files from failed recording (that can also be found in `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\Recording Manager\Temporary Recording Files\`) to the current recording folder.
6. Stop the recording. Recording Manager will generated the recording based on temp files from the failed recording.

Comment: Agreed. This works brilliantly on Windows 10.  The only thing I might add is that I occasionally need to kill the Skype Recording Manager between recordings.  To do that, you can use PowerShell: `Stop-Process -Name OcPubMgr -Force` or Command Prompt: `taskkill /IM OcPubMgr.exe`.

Comment: unfortunately for me in the  c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Communicator\Recording Manager\Temporary Recording Files\ folder also it is not showing the meeting folder which i expected. What need to be done now ?

Answer (score 8):

I know this an old post, but Skype will not convert the video until you are plugged with an AC cord. I had the same issues, and then plugged my laptop in and then the files started converting.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nates comment, sometimes if you plug laptop in before accessing recording manager it gets stuck. For me it was fixed with unplugging and replugging the cord while record manager was open.